# ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'. when trying to connect to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure-functions, blazor

I have a blazor app that intended for comparing our SQL Server databases.

In `appsettings.json` , I'm trying to set:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "SourceConnectionString": "Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=prod;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin@mycompany.com;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication='Active Directory Password';",
        "TargetConnectionString": "Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=dev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin@mycompany.com;Password=123;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication='Active Directory Password';"
    }
```

Note: `SourceConnectionString` and `TargetConnectionString` are used in different `.cs` like below:

```
namespace MsSQLDatabaseComparison.DbContexts;

public class SourceDbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public SourceDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("SourceConnectionString");
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() => new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
}
```

```
namespace MsSQLDatabaseComparison.DbContexts;

public class TargetDbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public TargetDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("TargetConnectionString");
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() => new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
}
```

Then I got errors:

[image]

Any suggestions are much appreciate on how to fix the connection to SQL Server?

Comment: Should `'Active Directory Password'` have the single quotes around it?

Comment: Seems like the error is that whatever provider you're using doesn't support the `Authentication` keyword. I'm unable to find any documentation online for that keyword although admittedly my searching was not exhaustive.

Comment: I'm with TimothyG... the Microsoft examples use `Authentication=Active Directory Password;` without the single quotes. But are you using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: I'll note that `System.Data.SqlClient` != `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: @Leo Install the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` NuGet package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
using SqlConnection = Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
```

Much thx to @Daniel Mann and @AlwaysLearning for pointing it out